# Validate form using jqueryvalidate.js and ckeditor Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Hello. I have a form that gets validated by jqueryvalidate.js. I have a drop down menu and the menu will be different when I choose "Library Asset" because I need to choose another drop down menu that is hidden.

The problem is, when I am not choose other menu that is not showing another drop down menu..
the required rules still implemented.. so the form can't be submitted except the one that is showing another drop down menu..

Can someone help me here?

This is my code:
View(Js):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showbook()
{       
    var domObj1 = document.getElementById('emptybox');
    var domObj2 = document.getElementById('showupbox');

    if(domObj1.style.display =='none')
    {
        domObj1.style.display = 'block';
        domObj2.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        domObj1.style.display = 'none';
        domObj2.style.display = 'block';
    }

}
function closebook()
{
    var domObj1 = document.getElementById('emptybox');
    var domObj2 = document.getElementById('showupbox');

    if(domObj1.style.display =='none')
    {
        domObj1.style.display = 'block';
        domObj2.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function showhidebook()
{
    console.log($('#CategoryAdviceSelect').val());
    if($('#CategoryAdviceSelect').val() == 1)
    {
        showbook();
    }
    else{
    closebook();
    }
}
```

My validation rules:

```
<script>

$().ready(function() {

    $("#feedback_form").validate({
    ignore: "input:hidden:not(input:hidden.required)",
    rules: {
        CategoryAdviceSelect:"required",
        Subject:"required",
        Advice:"required",
        BookSelect:"required"

    },
    messages: {
        CategoryAdviceSelect:"Please select one of category advice",
        Subject:"This field is required",
        Advice:"This field is required",
        BookSelect:"This field is required"
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().addClass("help-block");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass("help-block");
    }
});
});


</script>
```

And my html view

```
<div class="row-fluid ">

<div class="box">
<hr>
<div class="paragraph">
     <p>For enquiries about our services, write to: helpdesk@library.binus.ac.id.</p>

    <p>You may also reach us at our helpdesk number 62-21-5350660. We value your feedback. Please fill in the form below, and help us improve our services.</p>

    <p>Talk to me here
        <a href = 'ymsgr:sendim?me_lieza93'>
          <img src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=me_lieza93&m=g&t=1" border=0>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>

        <!--START FORM-->
        <form id="feedback_form" name="feedback_form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>feedback/feedback/insert_to_db" method="post" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">

                 <div class="control-group">

                    <!--FEEDBACK TYPE-->

                        <label class="span2 control-label" >Feedback for</label>

                        <div class="controls with-tooltip"> 
                        <select  class="input-tooltip span5" tabindex="2" id="CategoryAdviceSelect" name="CategoryAdviceSelect" onchange="showhidebook();" >
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Your Feedback For..</option>
                         <?php 
                            for($x = 0 ; $x < count($feedback) ; $x++) 
                            { ?> 
                                <option value="<?php echo $feedback[$x]['CategoryAdviceId']?>"><?php echo $feedback[$x]['CategoryAdviceName'] ?></option>
                            <?php 
                            } ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>  
                </div>

            <!--SUBJECT-->  
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="limiter" class="control-label">Subject</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="span5" maxlength="50" id="Subject" name="Subject" placeholder="Type Your Feedback Subject.."  />
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>                      
                </div>

            <div id="emptybox"></div>
            <!--CHOOSE BOOK-->  
            <div id="showupbox" style="display: none;">             
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Choose Book</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select  class="chzn-select span5" tabindex="2" id="BookSelect" name="BookSelect">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Your Feedback For..</option>
                             <?php 
                                for($y = 0 ; $y < count($booklist) ; $y++) 
                                { ?> 
                                    <option value="<?php echo $booklist[$y]['bi']?>"><?php echo $booklist[$y]['AssetTitle']?></option>
                                <?php 
                                } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>  
            <!--ADVICE-->   
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="limiter" class="control-label" >Suggestion</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo $this->ckeditor->editor("Advice",""); ?>;
                      </div>                        
                </div>

                <!--div class="alert alert-success">  
                      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>  
                      <strong>Success!</strong> Thanks for your feedback!   
                    </div--> 

                <div class="bton1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary round" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary round" type="refresh">Reset</button>
                    </div>
        </form> 
</div><!--END BOX-->
```

Comment: Have you tried jquery validate add rule and remove rule?

Comment: thanks for asking me finally I've find the result :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve this..

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {


    for(var name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances["Advice"].on("instanceReady", function() {
            // Set keyup event          
            this.document.on("keyup", updateValue);
            // Set paste event
            this.document.on("paste", updateValue);     
        }); 

        function updateValue() {
            CKEDITOR.instances["Advice"].updateElement(); 
            $('textarea').trigger('keyup');
        }
   } 

    $("#feedback_form").validate({
     ignore: 'input:hidden:not(input:hidden.required)',
        rules: {
            CategoryAdviceSelect:"required",
            Subject:"required",
            Advice:"required",
            BookSelect:{
                    required: function(element){
                    return $("#CategoryAdviceSelect").val()==1;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            CategoryAdviceSelect:"Please select one of category advice",
            Subject:"This field is required",
            Advice:"This field is required",
            BookSelect:"This field is required",
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
              if ($(element).attr('name') == 'Advice') {
                  $('#cke_Advice').after(error);
              } else {
                  element.after(error);
              }
          },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass("help-block");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass("help-block");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```